# How can I remove from richtextbox only the text that's Strikeout?

Tags: c#

Hello I have a little problem with a richtextbox, i tried to remove only the words that are Strikeout, but if i have a word that appears with Regular font then the word it's removed too. How can I remove only the words in Strikeout?

Here is my code:

```
        text = richTextBox2.Text;
        string[] destLine = richTextBox2.Text.Split(WordSeparaterss);
        foreach (string str in destLine)
        {
            int startIndex = 0;
            while (startIndex != -1)
            {
                startIndex = richTextBox2.Find(str, startIndex + 1,
                                richTextBox2.Text.Length,
                                RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                if (startIndex != -1)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Select(startIndex, str.Length);

                    if (richTextBox2.SelectionFont.Strikeout)
                    {
                        text = text.Replace(str, string.Empty);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the text for example, and i strikeout the text between " *** "

`***Deutschlektionen erlauben vertiefende Einblicke für den Aufbau der deutschen Sprache. Satzbau, Präpositionen, Pronomen und viele andere Themen werden kompakt präsentiert und mit einem berühmten Zitat veranschaulicht.
Deutschkurs - Grammatik***

 Gramatik und viele zum.`

And this is what i get from my code :

`ane wer
Gramatik zum.`

And I want to get only: `Gramatik und viele zum.`

Comment: it might help if you posted the value of `richTextBox2.Text` when there are some strikethrough and some normal words.

Comment: I guess your problem is that `und` and `viele` are found in the text and therefore replaced by `string.Empty`. `Grammatik` is found in the text but `Gramatik` (less `m`) will not be replaced. So essentially you work the replace on the entire text per word.

Comment: Yes, i know that it does this but i want to do like i explain , not like it shows to me. I need a code that do that..only the word strikeout to replace not all the words that are in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method checks length of current text. Then starting from end checks character by character. If it's style is `Strikeout` it s then removed. Note that the count starts from end. It is because after removing one letter or indexes are decreased. If you count from end the change of indexes will affect only the text that was already investigated.

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectAll();
int textLength = this.richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length;
for (int i = textLength; i >= 0; --i)
{
    this.richTextBox1.Select(i, 1);
    if (this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Strikeout)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.SelectedText = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the separator "***" , i have only the word strikeout. I want to verify every word in my text, and if it's strikeout then replace with string.empty, but i don't want to replace all words that are the same with my word strikeout.

Comment: Aaa, I didn't understand your question correctly. I thought you just refer to anything that's commented out. Sorry

Comment: @Irina I changed my answer to address your problem